# Access value from JavaScript object via array-string

Tags: javascript, json

my problem is that i have a json-object with and array into here an example.

```
var object = {
 'items':['entry1','entry2']
}
```

I want to access 'entry2' over a constant string that I receive and shouldn't be changed.

```
var string = 'items[1]';
```

The only way I'm solving this problem is over the eval function...

```
eval('object.'+string);
```

This returns me entry2.

Is there any other way to achieve this without using `eval()`?
Like `object[string]` or `object.string`

Comment: What are the possible values of  `string` ?

Comment: in this case 'items[0]' or 'items[1]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your string is always the same form, you could extract its parts using a regex :

```
var m = string.match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/);
var item = object[m[1]][+m[2]];
```

---

**Explanation :**

The regex builds two groups :

```
(\w+) : a string
\[(\d+)\] : some digits between brackets
```

and those groups are at index 1 and 2 of the array returned by [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

`+something` parses the number. It's not strictly needed here as the array accepts a string if it can be converted but I find the code more readable when this conversion is explicited.

Comment: this is the solution but I seem not to understand it correctly. Anyway it works and I have to check how the method is working. Thx :)

Comment: yeah, I've also found the method on google and it helped alot. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

On top of [dystroy's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612579/801544), you can use this function:

```
function getValueFromObject(object, key) {
  var m = key.match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/);
  return object[m[1]][+m[2]];
}
```

Example:

```
var object = {
 'items':['entry1','entry2']
}

var string = 'items[1]';

var value = getValueFromObject(object, string); //=> "entry2"
```

Comment: Does this really add something to my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the array from inside:

```
var entries = object.items // entries now is ['entry1','entry2']
```

Then you need to index that to get the second item (in position 1).  So you achieve what you want with:

```
var answer = entries[1] // answer is now 'entry2'
```

Of course, you can combine this to get both done in one step:

```
var answer = object.items[1] // answer is now 'entry2'
```

... I can see this is a contrived example, but please don't call your Objects 'object', or your Strings 'string' :s

Comment: it was just for the understanding ;) but I honor your advice

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
  object.items[1];
```

Comment: this isnt possible since items[1] is received as a string... that's my problem...

Comment: as I told before items[1] is received as a string from an request so it's not static code. It's a string = 'items[1]'